# Return to java7 in compiler compliance level

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using java7 to develop a project and I had no trouble. Then I tried to execute my project with Java6 changing the version in the compiler compliance level in Eclipse and I gave some errors in some jason file. So, I returned to Java7 but I still have the same errors of java6. How can I resolve?

Comment: Well what are the errors? And do you have project-specific settings, or is it delegating to the general Eclipse preferences?

Comment: When you change the compliance in eclipse it will prompt us to rebuild the project. Did you get that prompt?

Comment: You could try "Project / clean" in eclipse. Also make sure the project specific settings are OK, maybe you changed the workspace settings. Right-click project, select Properties and then "Java Compiler".

Comment: the error:Multiple markers at this line
- Unexpected token 'L'. Expected '{', '['.

Comment: Yes i rebuild the project and -i did the clean

Comment: Maybe you have also changed the JRE library version. Check it in Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries. Look for "JRE System Library".